# Problem with proof environment

Tags: proof-package

I've written a proof in LaTeX, and I looked up how to use the proof environment. From what I read, it should start with "Proof:" and end with \qed, but the PDF shows no changes. It simply displays the text verbatim. What could be the cause of this? My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document} 
\begin{proof}
    \noindent Assume that $R$ decides $HALT_{TM}$, and obtain a contradiction. Construct $S$ to decide $A_{TM}$, where $S$ operates as follows: \newline \newline 
    $S=$ ``On input $\langle M, w \rangle$, an encoding of a TM $M$ and a string $w$:
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Run TM $r$ on input $\langle M, w \rangle$.
    \item If $R$ rejects, reject
    \item If $R$ accepts, accept
    \item If $M$ has accepted, accept; if $M$ has rejected, reject."
    \end{enumerate}

    \noindent \newline If $R$ decides $HALT_{TM}$, then $S$ decides $A_{TM}$. Because $A_{TM}$ is undecidable, $HALT_{TM}$ must also be undecidable. 
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please fix your example to be a complete document that shows the problem. `proof` isn't defined by default but several packages define environments of this form so it is impossible to guess what definitions you are using.

Comment: Do you require a picture of the PDF? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: as posted the document produces the error `! LaTeX Error: Environment proof undefined.`  after an error you shouldn't really even look at the pdf, you need to fix the error first,

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. That's why I'm confused.

Comment: did you intend to load the `amsthm` package?

Comment: try the above document (not your original document) `proof` is not defined

Comment: Are you saying I should have, or that I did and shouldn't have?

Comment: meanwhile other comments, you should never need `\noindent` and certainly not `\noindent \newline`  also `\newline \newline` produces the warning that this produces output with maximum measure of badness: `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 17--19`  finally `$HALT_{TM}$` would be better as `$\mathrm{HALT}_{\mathrm{TM}}$` otherwise it will be typeset in math italic with spaced letters to look like a product of variables, not a word.

Comment: I am saying that the document posted above does not define a proof environment so you just get an error at that point which explains why it is not typeset as a proof. one way to define a proof environment is to load `amsthm`

Comment: Ah, I see. Is there a way to produce the same layout but remove the ``\newline \newline`` and so on?

Comment: just leave a blank line for a new paragraph, whether paragraphs are indented or set off by vertical space should be a global document setting not something controlled by `\noindent` etc in each case.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

The `proof` environment is not defined so you get the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment proof undefined.
```

a common way to define it is to load `amsthm` when you get a `proof` heading and qed box at the end.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document} 
\begin{proof}
    Assume that $R$ decides $\mathrm{HALT}_{\mathrm{TM}}$, and obtain a contradiction. Construct $S$ to decide $A_{\mathrm{TM}}$, where $S$ operates as follows: 

    $S={}$ ``On input $\langle M, w \rangle$, an encoding of a TM $M$ and a string $w$:
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Run TM $r$ on input $\langle M, w \rangle$.
    \item If $R$ rejects, reject
    \item If $R$ accepts, accept
    \item If $M$ has accepted, accept; if $M$ has rejected, reject."
    \end{enumerate}

     If $R$ decides $\mathrm{HALT}_{\mathrm{TM}}$, then $S$ decides $A_{\mathrm{TM}}$. Because $A_{\mathrm{TM}}$ is undecidable, $\mathrm{HALT}_{\mathrm{TM}}$ must also be undecidable. 
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess ShareLaTeX is missing some info. At least, from what I could see.

Comment: @user83024 i am sure that sharelatex is flagging errors if you look in the right place, also it can show you the log file which will also have the error message. I can't give details as I don't use it myself